# Grouping two tables, one above the other

Tags: tables, floats

I'd like to group two tables, one below the other, so they don't show separated ie. one in each page. What's the best way to achieve that? I've read about positioning them side by side, but not this.

Probably, I could create a custom float with `\usepackage{float}`, but I bet there is a simpler way (other than playing around with [htpb]).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Any number of tables, with their captions, can go in the same `table` environment (so long as they fit in a page).

Comment: But then they will show up in the Index of tables as the same table. I want them to be separate tables, yet be grouped.

Comment: It's the caption that produces the entry in the list of tables. Two captions, two entries.

Comment: Thank you. I was making a really wrong assumption there.

Comment: Anyway - is it possible to label each table separately, and then make references to them separately? I mean, I'm just trying, I added a different label for each one of the tables (right after the caption) and when clicking on a `autoref` link it always points to the first one.

Comment: Yes: Associate each `\caption{...}` with a `\label{...}`, and then issue `\ref` (or `\autoref`, `\cref`, etc) instruction to cross-reference the object(s) of interest.

Comment: @Arnaugir Every caption should have its own label.

Comment: You can take a look at the `floatrow` package:: its purpose is to group figures or tables as such — i.e. not as subfigures/tables, although it can manage them too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Any number of tables can go in a single `table` environment, along with their captions, so long as they fit in a page.

The entries in the list of tables are generated by the `\caption` command, so there will be two entries even if two tables are in the same `table` environment.

However, there will be a problem when the `caption` package is loaded together with `hyperref`, because the link in the list of tables or the ones made by `\ref` might bring to the first of the two tables. The `hypcap` package fixes it.

Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just to produce nonsense text

\usepackage{caption} % for better vertical separation
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypcap} % fix the links

\begin{document}
\title{A title}
\author{A. Uthor}

\maketitle

\listoftables

\section{A section}

A reference to the first table~\ref{tab:first} and one to the
second table~\ref{tab:second}, followed by nonsense text.

\kant

\begin{table}[htp]

\centering
\caption{First table}\label{tab:first}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
ab & cd \\
ab & cd \\
ab & cd \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\caption{Second table}\label{tab:second}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
ab & cd \\
ab & cd \\
ab & cd \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\kant

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a couple of options here:

Make the tables smaller by simply using `\small` or `\footnotesize` in your table.  E.g.:

```
\begin{table}\footnotesize
\caption{Table caption A}\label{tab:A}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
One & two\\
\end{tabular
\end{table}
```

Other option is setting one to be on top of the page and another one on the bottom:

```
\begin{table}[t!]
\caption{Table caption A}\label{tab:A}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
One & two\\
\end{tabular
\end{table}


\begin{table}[b!]
\caption{Table caption B}\label{tab:B}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
One & two\\
\end{tabular
\end{table}
```

Comment: Second option!!